# Heatmap does not show all the rows

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataset with 399 rows (`Words`) and 5 columns (`Dates`). I would like to visualise some information by heat maps. I have created a pivot table by using:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='Words', columns='Date', values='frequency', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Output:

```
Date    2018-02-18  2018-02-19  2018-02-20  2018-02-21  2018-02-22
Words                   
A   NaN NaN NaN 2.0 2.0
B   NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0
C   NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0
D   NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN
E   NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ...
RRR NaN 10.0    NaN NaN 90.0
SSS NaN 3.0 3.0 3.0 NaN
TTT NaN 4.0 NaN NaN NaN
UUU NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN
VVV NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0
ZZZ NaN NaN 1.0 NaN 1.0

399 rows × 5 columns
```

Then I have tried to create a heatmap using the following lines of code:

```
piv = pd.pivot_table(df, values="frequency",index=["Words"], columns=["Date"], fill_value=0)
ax = sns.heatmap(piv, square=False)
```

However the output shows only 20 of those 399 rows. Would it be possible to visualise all the rows in the heatmap? In case it would not be possible, how could I visualise only the most popular rows (i.e. rows that have greater frequency through time/dates)?

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output *does* show all the rows, but the y-labels are reduced as they would overlap too much and be unreadable.

If you don't have a frequency column, you can create one and set all values to `1` with `df['frequency'] = 1`. The aggregation function will then sum everything up.

You can sort the `piv` dataframe and take the 10 highest values with `idx = piv.sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).head(10).index`. Then, `piv.loc[idx]` will get just those rows in that order.

The code below shows the steps. It also rotates the tick labels to make them better readable in this particular case.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

N = 1000
abc = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[f'2018-02-{i:02d}' for i in np.random.randint(18, 23, N)],
                   'Words': [abc[i]+abc[j] for i,j  in np.random.randint(0, len(abc), (N, 2)) ] ,
                   'frequency': np.random.randint(1, 10, N)
                   })
# df['frequency'] = 1  # in case there wasn't a frequency column yet
piv = pd.pivot_table(df, values="frequency",index=["Words"], columns=["Date"], fill_value=0, aggfunc=np.sum)
idx = piv.sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).head(10).index
ax = sns.heatmap(piv.loc[idx], square=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0) # rotate the x labels to be horizontally again
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0) # rotate the y labels to be horizontally
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

PS: To show all the ticks, and all the labels (they can be too crowded) sorted alphabetically:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator

idx = piv.sort_values('Words', ascending=True).index
ax = sns.heatmap(piv.loc[idx], square=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(np.arange(0.5, len(idx) + 0.5, 1)))
ax.set_yticklabels(idx, rotation=0, fontsize=6)
```

Or to see the labels alternating left and right (to fit the double), a secondary axis could help:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(np.arange(0.5, len(idx) + 0.5, 2)))
ax.set_yticklabels(idx[::2], rotation=0, fontsize=6)

secax = ax.secondary_yaxis('right')
secax.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(np.arange(1.5, len(idx) + 0.5, 2)))
secax.set_yticklabels(idx[1::2], rotation=0, fontsize=6)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JohanC. May I ask you if it would be possible also to show all the rows? is there any limit? Maybe it could be hard to show and difficult to read with 399 rows! I do not know if increasing the size of figure, it could be different.  In case I set each `Words` as `frequency=1`, how could I determine the 10 words with highest frequency?

Comment: There isn't a limit on the rows shown (as long as memory allows it), but when the row heights get too small, you won' t be able to distinguish them. Also, there won't be enough space for the labels.

Comment: Thank you, @JohanC. So in case I would like to try with all the rows, I should just omit head(10), should I not?

Comment: Without `head(10)` you get all the rows in the given order. But it will not show all labels. There are too many of them.

Comment: I added an example how to see all labels, sorted alphabetically. If you can't read everything, zooming into some rows is possible.